# Find closest value for every row in a matrix from another matrix

Tags: r

I have generated 5 coordinates (each consisting of an x and a y variable, which are considered the "truth."

```
D <- 2 #amount of dimensions
K <- 5
events <- 2*K #number of events
truth <- matrix(data=runif(events, min = 0, max = 1), nrow=K)
```

Then I generated another set of coordinates, in this case two:

```
E <- 2    
test <- matrix(data=runif(2*E, min = 0, max = 1), nrow=E)
```

and now I would want to know which of these first five coordinates is closest (in a euclidian sense) to each of these two test coordinates. What is the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rdist` from the package `fields` to compute a Euclidean distance matrix between each row in `test` and each row in `truth`. First the data:

```
set.seed(123)  ## for reproducibility
D <- 2 #amount of dimensions
K <- 5
events <- 2*K #number of events
truth <- matrix(data=runif(events, min = 0, max = 1), nrow=K)
##          [,1]      [,2]
##[1,] 0.2875775 0.0455565
##[2,] 0.7883051 0.5281055
##[3,] 0.4089769 0.8924190
##[4,] 0.8830174 0.5514350
##[5,] 0.9404673 0.4566147

E <- 2    
test <- matrix(data=runif(2*E, min = 0, max = 1), nrow=E)
##          [,1]      [,2]
##[1,] 0.9568333 0.6775706
##[2,] 0.4533342 0.5726334
```

Compute the distance matrix using `rdist`:

```
library(fields)
d <- rdist(test,truth)
##          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
##[1,] 0.9205136 0.2252589 0.5884781 0.1461471 0.2215612
##[2,] 0.5525263 0.3379176 0.3228474 0.4302058 0.5007584
```

To find the `truth` row that is nearest to each `test` row, `apply` `which.min` over rows with `MARGIN=1`:

```
apply(d,1,which.min)
##[1] 4 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid having to calculate the distance for every row combination, avoid using the base `dist`, and do it without any external packages, you can manually code a Euclidean distance by making two conforming matrices first.

```
diffs   <- truth[rep(1:nrow(truth), nrow(test)),] -test[rep(1:nrow(test), each=nrow(truth)),]
eucdiff <- function(x) sqrt(rowSums(x^2))
max.col(-matrix(eucdiff(diffs), nrow=nrow(test), byrow=TRUE), "first")
#[1] 4 3
```

Using @aichao's data above.