# Applying a function by looping over two tables

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops

I have two tables, d1 and d2, that simply contain cartesian points and their name. They look like this:

```
d1:

       x1        y1      point
1  -36.70045 -35.57741     a
2  -31.71920 -31.95160     b
3  -33.42082 -32.52115     c
4  -35.01071 -32.14848     d
5  -30.82340 -35.35468     e
6  -32.48995 -35.91305     f
7  -31.13327 -35.50498     g
8  -33.14196 -37.89258     h
9  -35.11322 -32.48860     i
10 -33.04845 -34.96242     j

d2:

      x2        y2      point
1  -21.84797 -27.29278     k
2  -27.96603 -21.43688     l
3  -24.57574 -25.98523     m
4  -20.21674 -26.02366     n
5  -22.54094 -26.86359     o
6  -27.66791 -25.16078     p
7  -20.78323 -20.54069     q
8  -27.26773 -23.25467     r
9  -26.76333 -25.70280     s
10 -20.38453 -23.92657     t
```

I am using a simple distance formula we learned in primary school that takes two points and calculates the distance between them

```
dist(x1 = , x2 =, y1 = , y2 = )
```

I know this might be trival for some, but bear with me. I want go through d1 and compare each point to the points in d2 to find which point is the closest to the point in d1. I want to add to d1 a row with how far that nearest point is and the name of that point.

So for example, I would want my function to start with point "a" in d1 and plug it in for x1 and y1 in my function. For x2 and y2 in the distance function, I want it to loop down d2 and plug points k - t. Then, I need it to return the distance to the nearest point and its point name. I have tried a double loop but nothing seems to work. I know with your brilliant insights ill be one step closer to mastering R!

Comment: This covers similar ground I believe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668623/find-closest-value-for-every-row-in-a-matrix-from-another-matrix/40669071

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` strategy, it may be easier to understand (perhaps)

- I used `purrr::map2_*` functions to iterate `d1$x1` and `d1$y1` over all values of `d2`
- syntax inside `map` function is also written in tidyverse style

  - First, a distance variable say `dist` is mutated inside `d2` for the given two arguments
  - Second, `d2` is then filtered for `min` of `dist`
  - lastly, `point` is `pull`ed for point and `dist` is `pull`ed for distance.

```r
d1 <- read.table(text = '       x1        y1      point
1  -36.70045 -35.57741     a
2  -31.71920 -31.95160     b
3  -33.42082 -32.52115     c
4  -35.01071 -32.14848     d
5  -30.82340 -35.35468     e
6  -32.48995 -35.91305     f
7  -31.13327 -35.50498     g
8  -33.14196 -37.89258     h
9  -35.11322 -32.48860     i
10 -33.04845 -34.96242     j', header = T)

d2 <- read.table(text = '      x2        y2      point
1  -21.84797 -27.29278     k
2  -27.96603 -21.43688     l
3  -24.57574 -25.98523     m
4  -20.21674 -26.02366     n
5  -22.54094 -26.86359     o
6  -27.66791 -25.16078     p
7  -20.78323 -20.54069     q
8  -27.26773 -23.25467     r
9  -26.76333 -25.70280     s
10 -20.38453 -23.92657     t', header = T)

suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
d1 %>% mutate(nearest_point = map2_chr(x1, y1, ~ d2 %>% mutate(dist = sqrt((x2 - .x)^2 + (y2 - .y)^2)
                                                               ) %>% 
                                         filter(dist == min(dist)) %>%
                                         pull(point)
                                       ),
              shortest_dist = map2_dbl(x1, y1, ~ d2 %>% mutate(dist = sqrt((x2 - .x)^2 + (y2 - .y)^2)
                                                               ) %>% 
                                         filter(dist == min(dist)) %>%
                                         pull(dist)
                                       )
              )
#>           x1        y1 point nearest_point shortest_dist
#> 1  -36.70045 -35.57741     a             p     13.787420
#> 2  -31.71920 -31.95160     b             p      7.907477
#> 3  -33.42082 -32.52115     c             p      9.341896
#> 4  -35.01071 -32.14848     d             p     10.136304
#> 5  -30.82340 -35.35468     e             s     10.471053
#> 6  -32.48995 -35.91305     f             s     11.706553
#> 7  -31.13327 -35.50498     g             s     10.732153
#> 8  -33.14196 -37.89258     h             s     13.757822
#> 9  -35.11322 -32.48860     i             p     10.446511
#> 10 -33.04845 -34.96242     j             p     11.181340
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Glad that it helped.  please also consider it [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).  You may upvote as many answers per question, as you feel are correct.

Comment: Thank you AnilGoyal, this is so beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

We can take advantage of vectorization in R.

```r
dists <- outer(seq_len(nrow(d1)), seq_len(nrow(d2)),
               function(i1, i2) sqrt( (d1$x1[i1] - d2$x2[i2])^2 + (d1$y1[i1] - d2$y2[i2])^2 ))
dists
#           [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]     [,5]      [,6]     [,7]      [,8]      [,9]    [,10]
#  [1,] 17.00680 16.62061 15.460223 19.05221 16.62596 13.787420 21.89659 15.518574 14.009078 20.04872
#  [2,] 10.91539 11.16448  9.307341 12.94013 10.49420  7.907477 15.80520  9.769963  7.975472 13.88798
#  [3,] 12.69908 12.35378 10.997895 14.71615 12.26294  9.341896 17.41379 11.123316  9.529537 15.61447
#  [4,] 14.02981 12.82053 12.119169 16.01171 13.54346 10.136304 18.36197 11.792099 10.467381 16.77871
#  [5,] 12.06452 14.20809 11.261432 14.12690 11.86161 10.671116 17.89579 12.611623 10.471053 15.47810
#  [6,] 13.69528 15.16659 12.696312 15.76172 13.44900 11.784031 19.32244 13.693289 11.706553 17.03575
#  [7,] 12.39585 14.42022 11.559708 14.45912 12.18613 10.909225 18.19487 12.845719 10.732153 15.79858
#  [8,] 15.48903 17.25052 14.668507 17.54801 15.29772 13.858714 21.30320 15.772602 13.757822 18.91564
#  [9,] 14.24652 13.16141 12.382742 16.23886 13.77327 10.446511 18.65747 12.116814 10.759542 17.03651
# [10,] 13.57476 14.44892 12.344098 15.63823 13.26645 11.181340 18.93203 13.057110 11.191215 16.79776
d1$dist <- apply(dists, 1, min)
d1$point2 <- d2$point[ apply(dists, 1, which.min) ]
d1
#           x1        y1 point      dist point2
# 1  -36.70045 -35.57741     a 13.787420      p
# 2  -31.71920 -31.95160     b  7.907477      p
# 3  -33.42082 -32.52115     c  9.341896      p
# 4  -35.01071 -32.14848     d 10.136304      p
# 5  -30.82340 -35.35468     e 10.471053      s
# 6  -32.48995 -35.91305     f 11.706553      s
# 7  -31.13327 -35.50498     g 10.732153      s
# 8  -33.14196 -37.89258     h 13.757822      s
# 9  -35.11322 -32.48860     i 10.446511      p
# 10 -33.04845 -34.96242     j 11.181340      p
```

The `outer` function creates an cartesian product of the two arguments, which we'll use as row indices on the two frames. The anonymous function is called once with (in this case) 100 integers in `i1` and 100 integers in `i2`; if we debug the function, we'd see:

```r
outer(seq_len(nrow(d1)), seq_len(nrow(d2)), function(i1, i2) { browser(); sqrt( (d1$x1[i1] - d2$x2[i2])^2 + (d1$y1[i1] - d2$y2[i2])^2 ); })
# Called from: FUN(X, Y, ...)
# Browse[1]> 
debug at #1: sqrt((d1$x1[i1] - d2$x2[i2])^2 + (d1$y1[i1] - d2$y2[i2])^2)
# Browse[2]> 
i1
#   [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3
#  [64]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# Browse[2]> 
i2
#   [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7
#  [64]  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

(Note the full-combination of `i1`-v-`i2`.)

This will calculate the distance from all points in `d1` to all points in `d2`. Since you're talking euclidean, I thought it more efficient to do it manually instead of using `dist`, but you can use whatever function you like, with one caveat: it must accept all values at once.

For instance, if the distance function you want to use requires that its four arguments are length-1, then you will need to loop over all of the values (`i1[1]`-v-`i2[1]`, then `i1[2]`-v-`i2[1]`, etc). I don't think this is necessary or even advised if you can stick with vectorized calcs like this.

The output from `outer` is a matrix, with the rows here coming from the first argument (row indices for `d1`). (Pro tip: knowing which is which is easier to know and confirm when the two arguments are different lengths.)

We can then `apply` over the rows to find the shortest distance and the `d2$point` associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using other packages: Using `laGP` package:

```
dist_matrix <- sqrt(laGP::distance(d1[,1:2], d2[,1:2]))
id <- max.col(-dist_matrix)
min_distance <- dist_matrix[cbind(seq(nrow(d1)), id)]
cbind(d1, min_distance, min_point = d2[id, 3])

          x1        y1 point min_distance min_point
1  -36.70045 -35.57741     a    13.787420         p
2  -31.71920 -31.95160     b     7.907477         p
3  -33.42082 -32.52115     c     9.341896         p
4  -35.01071 -32.14848     d    10.136304         p
5  -30.82340 -35.35468     e    10.471053         s
6  -32.48995 -35.91305     f    11.706553         s
7  -31.13327 -35.50498     g    10.732153         s
8  -33.14196 -37.89258     h    13.757822         s
9  -35.11322 -32.48860     i    10.446511         p
10 -33.04845 -34.96242     j    11.181340         p
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using only dplyr. It is based on a cross join `d1 %>% full_join(d2, by = character())` to get all combinations and then we can calculate the distance (vectorized) and finally we filter the row with the smallest distance per `point.x`.

```r
library(dplyr)

d1 %>%
  full_join(d2, by = character()) %>% 
  mutate(dist = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)) %>% 
  group_by(point.x) %>% 
  filter(dist == min(dist))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 7
#> # Groups:   point.x [10]
#>       x1    y1 point.x    x2    y2 point.y  dist
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 -36.7 -35.6 a       -27.7 -25.2 p       13.8 
#>  2 -31.7 -32.0 b       -27.7 -25.2 p        7.91
#>  3 -33.4 -32.5 c       -27.7 -25.2 p        9.34
#>  4 -35.0 -32.1 d       -27.7 -25.2 p       10.1 
#>  5 -30.8 -35.4 e       -26.8 -25.7 s       10.5 
#>  6 -32.5 -35.9 f       -26.8 -25.7 s       11.7 
#>  7 -31.1 -35.5 g       -26.8 -25.7 s       10.7 
#>  8 -33.1 -37.9 h       -26.8 -25.7 s       13.8 
#>  9 -35.1 -32.5 i       -27.7 -25.2 p       10.4 
#> 10 -33.0 -35.0 j       -27.7 -25.2 p       11.2


# the data
d1 <- read.table(text = '       x1        y1      point
1  -36.70045 -35.57741     a
2  -31.71920 -31.95160     b
3  -33.42082 -32.52115     c
4  -35.01071 -32.14848     d
5  -30.82340 -35.35468     e
6  -32.48995 -35.91305     f
7  -31.13327 -35.50498     g
8  -33.14196 -37.89258     h
9  -35.11322 -32.48860     i
10 -33.04845 -34.96242     j', header = T)

d2 <- read.table(text = '      x2        y2      point
1  -21.84797 -27.29278     k
2  -27.96603 -21.43688     l
3  -24.57574 -25.98523     m
4  -20.21674 -26.02366     n
5  -22.54094 -26.86359     o
6  -27.66791 -25.16078     p
7  -20.78323 -20.54069     q
8  -27.26773 -23.25467     r
9  -26.76333 -25.70280     s
10 -20.38453 -23.92657     t', header = T)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>